# I can't search correctly place in Leaflet map with GeoSearch

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding

I'm using a plugin for leaflet map geosearch https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch this is the repository. My code is very simple but I can't get the result in my map. 
I don't know what is happening. The error I get in the console is

> TypeError: can't convert undefined to object

I expect when click on the result of the search I get a marker similar to this website have in the Google Map section https://investigadoresparaguayosenelmundo.com/registration/

Here is my code :

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
    integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
    crossorigin=""/>
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
    integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
    crossorigin=""></script>
    <!--CDN para agregar los cluster de Leaflet-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster@1.4.1/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
    <!--CDN para el plugin de fullscreen del mapa-->
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/Leaflet.fullscreen.min.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/leaflet.fullscreen.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <!--CDN para agregar la barra de busqueda-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.css"/>
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFtER leaflet.js, when using with leaflet -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-geosearch@3.0.0/dist/geosearch.umd.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leafletMap-registration"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#leafletMap-registration {
        height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
}
```

Javascript:

```
// you want to get it of the window global
    const providerOSM = new GeoSearch.OpenStreetMapProvider();

    //leaflet map
    var leafletMap = L.map('leafletMap-registration', {
    fullscreenControl: true,
    // OR
    fullscreenControl: {
        pseudoFullscreen: false // if true, fullscreen to page width and height
    },
    minZoom: 2
    }).setView([0,0], 2);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(leafletMap);

    const search = new GeoSearch.GeoSearchControl({
        provider: providerOSM,
        style: 'bar',
        searchLabel: 'Buscar institución',
        autoClose: true,
    });

    leafletMap.addControl(search);
```

https://jsbin.com/lukikafalo/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Can't be reproduced after upgrading `leaflet-geosearch` to v3.0.4, maybe due to https://github.com/smeijer/leaflet-geosearch/commit/d6727a1c1ba276369a575b17c8eeca9fee8db16d

Comment: But I think I'm using  v3.0.0 (I think), look my HTML, where I add the plugin.

Comment: Upgrade to 3.0.4, problem should go away.

Comment: @IvanSanchez thank you bro, youre my livesaver, in the official docs the cdn is not updated :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the refs for your element.

In order to show the results lat lng on the map by placing a marker, you need to use keep result: true.

Use my elaborative blog:

https://medium.com/@jadhavshivam0228/open-street-maps-vuejs-integration-39c39b85b5bc